# Why is my bash string comparison of two identical strings always false?

Tags: bash, shell, logical-operators

I'm trying to write a simple little script to query a 3g connection, and if the connection has dropped, instigate a reconnection.

My problem is in checking the output of the command - two seemingly equal strings are not evaluated as equal. I'm sure there's a noob error in here somewhere!

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Checking connection"
a="Not connected."
b=$(./sakis3g status --console)

if [[ "$a"!="$b" ]]; then 
    echo "Strings not equal:"
    echo "$a"
    echo "$b"
else 
    echo "Strings equal!!"
fi
```

The output when run:

```
user@mypc:~$ ./test_3g.sh 
Checking connection
Strings not equal:
Not connected.
Not connected.
```

When running `./test_3g.sh | cat -A`:

```
user@mypc:~$ ./test_3g.sh | cat -A
Checking connection$
Strings not equal:$
Not connected.$
Not connected.$
```

Comment: There's no extraneous newline at the end, right?

Comment: Try `./test_3g.sh | cat -A`.  If your `cat` doesn't support the `-A` option, try `./test_3g.sh | cat -v`.

Comment: I don't think there's any extraneous whitespace, but would be happy to be corrected on that. @Keith, I have added the output from the pipe to cat -A to the question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to put spaces around operators:

```
if [[ "$a" != "$b" ]]; then ...
```

Without spaces you end up with a single string, equivalent to `"$a!=$b"`. And testing just a string returns true if that string is non-empty...

Comment: You beat me to that by 15 seconds!

Comment: Without the spaces, the expression is a single string `"Not connected.!=Not connected."`.  As a bash expression, a string is treated as true if its length is non-zero; `[[ STRING ]]` is equivalent to `[[ -n STRING]]`.  (`info bash`, search for `\[\[`, then follow the note "Bash Conditional Expressions".)

Comment: Beat me to it my 15 minutes +1 for the "$a!=$b" explanation

Comment: Bash has some, let say, interesting parsing mechanics :D

Answer (score 6):

Use `case/esac`. If you don't have to mess with `if/else`'s nitty gritty nuances

```
case "$a" in
"$b" ) echo "ok";;
*) echo "not ok";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably sakis3g program print message to stderr instead of stdout. In this case you compare your message with empty string. Try to redirect stderr to stdout:

```
b=$(./sakis3g status --console 2>&1)
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it, sorry! I am getting a result stored in `b` with or without your addition.